# Writing a powershell script to copy files with certain extension from one folder to another

Tags: powershell

I would like to write a powershell script that gets the following parameters as input:
Folder to copy from, extensions allows, folder to copy to and a boolean indicating if the change should restart IIS, username and password.
What cmdlets should I be looking at considering that I am copying to a remote server?
How do I read the parameters into variables?
How do I restart IIS?

Cosidering that I might want to copy multiple folders, how do I write a powershell script that invokes a powershell script?

Comment: Wow, sorry for a delay in any response...  Do you still need help?

Comment: Yes, I don't really know how to restart IIS? How do I make sure the files are really copied?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` allows you to list files and directories, including recursively with filename filters. `Copy-Item` allows you to copy a file.

There is a lot of overlap in terms of selecting the files, often `Copy-Item` on its own is sufficient depending on the details of what you need (eg. do you want to retain the folder structure?)

To copy all `*.foo` and `*.bar` from StartFolder to DestFolder:

```
Copy-Item -path "StartFolder" -include "*.foo","*.bar" -Destination "DestFolder"
```

If you need to preserve the folder structure things get harder because you need to build the destination folder name, something like:

```
$sourcePath = 'C:\StartFolder'
$destPath = 'C:\DestFolder'

Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse -Include '*.foo', '*.bar' | Foreach-Object `
    {
        $destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -Replace [regex]::Escape($sourcePath), $destPath)
        if (!(Test-Path $destDir))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir | Out-Null
        }
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination $destDir
    }
```

But `robocopy` is likely to be easier:

```
robocopy StartFolder DestFolder *.foo *.bar /s
```

In the end the way to choose will depend on the details of what's needed.

(In the above I've avoided aliases (e.g. `Copy-Item` rather than `copy`) and explicitly use parameter names even if they are positional.)

Comment: Doesnt work, I tried: `Copy-Item -path "C:\Users\username\Pictures\" -include "*.JPG", "*.PNG"  -Destination "D:\"` with and without -recurse - nothing happens

Answer (score 6):

I can't address the IIS portion, but the file copy while preserving the directory structure can be a lot simpler than shown in the other answers:

```
Copy-Item -path "StartFolder" -Recurse -Include "*.foo","*.bar" -Destination "DestFolder" -Container
```

The `-Container` argument is the magic part that will replicate the structure in the destination as it is in the source.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work with `-Include`... though I can get it to copy everything without `-Include`

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for me is

```
Copy-Item -path 'c:\SourceFolder\*.foo' -destination 'c:\DestFolder'
```

Other solutions that use `-Include` parameter didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As some people mentioned here **-Include** doesn't work.

To make it work with nested folders I used two steps approach: 'filter' + delete empty folders

```
#copy with folder structure
Copy-Item -path $source -Recurse -Filter "*.foo" -Destination $destination -Container

#remove empty folders
dir $destination -Directory -Recurse |
    %{ $_.FullName} |
    sort -Descending |
    where { !@(ls -force $_) } |
    rm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS7, you can use native component to replicate content between IIS servers:
http://blog.theplanet.com/2010/05/18/mirroring-server-content-and-configuration-in-iis7/